# How to specify valid content-range in header for request: Method-Put

Tags: python, python-requests, azure-devops-rest-api

I am making a REQUEST to upload a doc file, with method: PUT with below config's:

```
     #Upload file (Testfile.doc) size is 11kb.
     with open(Testfile.doc, "rb") as f:
         Test_file=f.read()
     url = organization_url+attachment_ID+apiversion # when i hit this url in browser, i see the attachment doc file to get download.
     Header = {"Content-Type":"application/octet-stream","Content-Range":"bytes 0-11100/*"}
     Initiate_Request = requests.put(url=url,header=Header,data=Test_file,auth=('',PAT))
     print("Attachment_details:-",Initiate_Request.text) ## {"count":1,"value":{"Message":"Content-Range specified in the attachment upload request is not valid."}}
     print("Attachment_details_Status_Code:-",Initiate_Request.status_code)  ## <Response [400]>
```

Any suggestions on how to specify the valid content-range for the above request.

Comment: I have phrased the header as: {"Content-Type":"application/octet-stream","Content-Range":"bytes 0-131/11100"} & the response is {"count":1,"value":{"Message":"Content-Range values don't match the length of the file content. "}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my purpose:

```
{"Content-Type":"application/octet-stream","Content-Length":"11100","Content-Range":"bytes 0-11099/11100"}
```

Comment: Normally the range can be defined as, if the file size is 11kb, range can be defined as 0-(11100-1) /11100..it will solve the problem